# Is it "falsy" or "falsey"?

Tags: terminology, orthography, suffixes, computing, silent-letters

I have seen both spellings of this word, *falsy* and *falsey*.

It can mean "something that is equivalent to false" in computer science, such as "The only two falsy values in the Ruby Language are false and nil".

What is the correct usage of this word?

Comment: I've never heard the term.  We just say *false* where I come from: "The two false values in Perl are the number 0 and the empty string (that is, the string whose length is 0), as well as anything that evaluates to one of these two, including the undefined value."

Comment: @tchrist Well, `null` is not `false`, although it is false-like because it might be evaluated as `false`. I'm sure "truthy" has come up before (although that might have been on SO).

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross I do not know what this `null` is, nor even `false`, since neither are reserved words or even defined identifiers where I come from. However, in [DMR-ese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie), `NULL` is certainly a false value, considering it is `#define`d to be `0`. Perhaps you are thinking of `"\0"`, which is true since it points to something. However, even though `p` when set to `"\0"` is necessarily true, `*p` is false since its pointee is `(char *)0`.

Comment: In many databases, `null` is a particular value which is actually nothing at all, not even zero. Similarly `false` is a Boolean value, which is neither `null` nor zero. But to work with either `null` or `false` they may need to be given a numeric value (generally zero): `null`, `false` and zero are "false-like", or falsy. Similarly truthy is true-like: non-`null`, `true` or non-zero.

Comment: But we have heard *truthiness* recently.

Comment: Perhaps a better word is *false-like*; for example "The only two *false*-like values in the Ruby Language is false and nil". Certainly I have never heard the term *falsy* - it just sounds made up to me.

Comment: The only spelling I know for what those two non-words sound like is "falsie": Main Entry: falsie Function: noun Inflected Form:-s 
Etymology: 1false + -ie : a breast-shaped usually fabric or rubber cup that is used to pad a brassiere — usually used in plural [falsies]" (from M-W 3rd Unabridged Dictionary).

Comment: I came here to see if one is preferred over the other. I'm leaning towards _falsy_ because it more clearly reads to me like "fol-see", whereas _falsey_ reads to me like "fail-see".

Comment: @Matt the problem with `false-like` is you've got a really common operator in the middle of the word there. generally you want to keep computer science jargon from breaking the code that it'll be used in.

Answer (score 65):

I've always seen *falsy* and *truthy*. *Falsey* is a perfectly acceptable alternative and gives me just as many search results. The word is unfortunately too new to provide good sources. [The ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) uses “⟦ToBoolean⟧” to refer to the interpretation of of non-Boolean values as Booleans, but makes no use of *truthy* or *falsy*.

These terms are widely used in discussions of dynamically typed programming languages such as JavaScript, Ruby, and Python, in which there is a Boolean data type but other values which can also behave like the Booleans `true` and `false`. It is a way to distinguish between *false* the noun and *false* the adjective:

- “*x* is `false`” (clear)
- “*x* is false” (ambiguous: is *x* `false` or is it a different false value?)
- “*x* is falsy” (clear)

As [tchrist points out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109996/#comment223142_109996), Perl is a notable exception because it lacks a Boolean type, so falsy values are just called *false*, in the adjectival sense.

Comment: How about `truthy` vs `truethy` (or `truethey`)?

Comment: @PeterV well to follow @Webveloper 's reasoning, it should be `truθy` instead.  Er...except that it's not so easy to type :)

Comment: @Webveloper although if compression is used it will probably only add O(1) bytes ;)

Comment: Seems like "falsy" is the preferred way, see the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: @Suncat2000 if that's a joke, it's a bad/misleading one. the MDN web docs are a wiki. if *falsy* is being used on those pages, it's by definition the preferred term of the community.

Comment: "... it's by definition the preferred term of the community."  No it's not. It's just the preferred term of the person who wrote the article.  As this answer mentions, the term "falsey" (or "falsy")  is so new, and not exceedingly common,  that "the community"  - that is, who ever happens upon the article - simply accepts the word as is, without notice of either the presence or absence of the 'e', since with either spelling, it's meaning is clear.

Comment: MDN has spoken. "Falsy" it is.

Comment: [Google Books Ngram Viewer: falsy/falsey, 1800-2019](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=falsy%2Cfalsey&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 8):

The only such word currently attested by the OED is the plural noun ***falsies***, whose sense is given as:

> A padded brassière; breast-pads.

It has [its own Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsies), one which I must advise you is unlikely to be work-friendly *in sensu stricto*.

Comment: For some geeky reason, the computer programming world has long maintained a tradition of using words in new ways, with a studied obliviousness to their prior, rude meanings: for example, 'dump'. 'Falsey' is merely another word in this long, and quite useful, tradition.

Comment: @MarkDBlackwell - Do note that "dump" has a long (and un-treasured) tradition in the computer programming world, likely going back to the mid-60s.  And if you think that this use of the word is not "rude" you've never had a 3-foot-high stack of "dump" dropped on your desk Friday afternoon.

Comment: @MarkDBlackwell In addition to Hot Licks' response, I'd say that "dump" in the CS sense, both as noun and verb, is merely another application of its preexisting meanings even without the vulgar one, particularly the ones related to unloading/releasing contents. (For example, "dump truck".)

Answer (score 6):

Given that it is a term with a specific meaning used by programmers, I searched stackoverflow.com to see how that programming community have used it.

- 9,155 results for *falsy* (7,674 results for *"falsy"* in quotes)
- 3,920 results for *falsey* (3,302 results for *"falsey"* in quotes)

This seems to indicate that both versions are in use, and that *falsy* is preferred.

Comment: But I'm sure if you compared the frequency to other similar terms, both spellings would hardly ever be used.  I've been in the computer biz for 50 years and I don't recall running across either term.

Comment: Some programming languages do not have the concept of "falsy" at all. It is related to the concept of loose vs strict typing. I think that strictly-typed languages (C, Java) might not have a need for the word. I mostly work with loosely-typed languages, such as JavaScript and PHP, and in those communities I have encountered it quite often. People also use alternative phrases such as "evaluates to false".